# Can I get some key values from an object?

Tags: javascript

```
let source = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5}



let result = (function make('a','c','e'){
    //Who can complete this code?
})()

console.log(result) // {a:1,c:3,e:5}
```

Comment: `//Who can complete this code?` ? The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: `Who can complete this  code?` - Answer:  No one without a bit of effort.

Comment: you could use this function `({a,c,e}) => ({a,c,e})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of different ways to do this but I would iterate over the [object entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and only return those key/values where the key is one of the function arguments.

```js
let source = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 };

function filterObj(...args) {
  return Object.entries(source).reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
    if (args.includes(k)) a[k] = v;
    return a;
  }, {});
}

console.log(filterObj('a', 'c', 'e'));
```